# Storm Nimbus failed to start due the first zookeeper server is down

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I set up Apache Storm 0.9.3 in fully distributed mode (3 nodes) that leverages a fully distributed Apache Zookeeper cluster (3.4.6) consisting of 3 nodes. I did the following testing and found out that Storm Nimbus failed to start if the first zookeeper server in the configuration `storm.yaml` is down or temporary unreachable.

Test #1:

- bring up all three zookeeper nodes
- start nimbus, supervisor, ui on the storm master node, and launch supervisor on other two nodes
- in this case, everything goes well

Test #2:

- shut down one of the three zookeeper nodes (zookeeper is still functional)
- start nimbus, supervisor, ui on the storm master node, and launch supervisor on other two nodes
- in this case, if the failed zookeeper node happened to be the first one in `storm.zookeeper.servers`, if fails to start neither nimbus nor supervisor on the master node.

I am wondering if any of you guys encounter this problem? Is it something going unexpected or something going wrong with my configuration? Or something else?

My configuration is listed below

```
storm.zookeeper.servers :
    - "zookeeper1.hostname.local"
    - "zookeeper2.hostname.local"
    - "zookeeper3.hostname.local"
nimbus.host             : storm-master.hostname.local
nimbus.thrift.port      : 6627
storm.zookeeper.port    : 2181
supervisor.slots.ports  :
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
ui.port                 : 8744
storm.local.dir         : /opt/apache-storm-0.9.3/storm-local
```